# WordPress Custom Drop Down Menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm using the WordPress Menu in my theme but I'm trying to style up the CSS correctly. It's not showing the drop down menu in the right way. I don't suppose anyone could check it out and see what's happening? I'll put both the HTML and CSS below for you, along with a link to the live test page.

[Live Test Page](http://test.snowflakesoftware.com/)

```
<div id="nav-primary" class="nav"><nav>
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu' ) ); /* if the visitor is logged in, this primary navigation will be displayed */
    } else {
        wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); /* if the visitor is NOT logged in, this primary navigation will be displayed. if a single menu should be displayed for both conditions, set the same menues to be displayed under both conditions through the Wordpress backend */
    } ?>
</nav></div><!--#nav-primary-->
```

There is a lot of rubbish in the CSS below but I can strip that out once I've got the function working, here is the CSS...

```
#nav-primary {width: 600px;}
#nav-primary {list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 68px; position: relative; z-index: 500; font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;}
#nav-primary ul, #nav-primary li {list-style: none;}
#nav-primary li {float: left;}
#nav-primary li a {float: left; display: block; height: 68px; line-height: 68px; background: none; color: #FFFFFF; text-decoration: none; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 10px;}
/*#nav-primary table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;}*/

#nav-primary li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 200;}
#nav-primary li:hover > a {color: #00e5c3; background: #000000; border-bottom: 3px solid #00e5c3;}
#nav-primary li:hover > a.sub {color: #00e5c3; background-color: #000000; border-bottom: 3px solid #00e5c3;}
#nav-primary li.current a {color: #00e5c3; background: #000000; border-bottom: 3px solid #00e5c3;}
#nav-primary li a.sub {background: none;}
#nav-primary li.current a.sub {color: #00e5c3; background: #000000; border-bottom: 3px solid #00e5c3;}

#nav-primary :hover ul {left: 0px; top: 71px; width: 120px; background: none;}

/* keep the 'next' level invisible by placing it off screen. */
#nav-primary ul, #nav-primary :hover ul ul {position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: -9999px; width: 0px; height: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; list-style: none;}
#nav-primary :hover ul :hover ul {left: 120px; top: -1px; background: #000; white-space: nowrap; width: 185px; z-index: 200; height: auto;}
#nav-primary :hover ul li {margin: 0px; border-bottom: none;}
#nav-primary :hover ul li a {width: 185px; padding: 0px; text-indent: 10px; background: #000; color: #FFF; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; border-bottom: none;}
#nav-primary :hover ul li a.fly {background: #000;}
#nav-primary :hover ul :hover {background-color: #00e5c3; color: #000; border-bottom: none;}
#nav-primary :hover ul :hover a.fly {background-color: #00e5c3; color: #000; border-bottom: none;}
#nav-primary :hover ul li.currentsub a {background: #FFF; color: #000;}
#nav-primary :hover ul li.currentsub a.fly {background: #FFF; color: #000;}
```

Hopefully someone can help! Been racking my brain for a while on this and just need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you want to do is:

```
#nav-primary :hover ul {left: 0px; top: 71px; background: none;}
```

Instead of the following:

```
#nav-primary :hover ul {left: 0px; top: 71px; width: 120px; background: none;}
```

This will stop your menu from jumping vertically when you hover over them.

Secondly, your drop down menus have no styling. Did you try this out yourself yet? Because I cannot seem to find it on the page.

PS. To test how it looks, I have hidden the sub-menus with a simple:

```
.sub-menu{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Blackunknown, I've replaced the CSS code completely, with another simple drop down menu. Just need to style up the menu now. Thanks anyway!